# I want to assign a user to my card from the User table, but its not working for me

Tags: django, django-models

The error is:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column
> user_awaycardholder.assigned_user_id does not exist LINE 1:
> ...der"."id", "user_awaycardholder"."display_id_id", "user_away...

I am not able to create `AwayCardHolder` can you please tell me what is the above error ??? and How to fix that ?

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    youtube_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    instagram_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logo')
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/profile')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    messanger = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    parent_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    is_child = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_office = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    hits = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, default=0)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Data"

    def __str__(self):
        name = self.user.first_name + ' ' + str(self.user.id)
        return str(name)

class AwayCard(models.Model):
    Away_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    my_admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    display_id = models.CharField(default='', max_length=30)
    is_assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        name = str(self.display_id)
        return str(name)



class AwayCardHolder(models.Model):
    display_id = models.OneToOneField(AwayCard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigned_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_awaycardholder", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        name = self.display_id
        return str(name)
```

Comment: is the field `assigned_user_id` present in the table `user_awaycardholder` in your database?

Comment: Arun I have added all the Models above, please check above ,I am so confused now

Comment: I was asking if you have the actual column in your actual database table. Can you use some sort of database viewer and look into your database table?

Comment: no I have assigned_user but not assigned_user_id

Comment: hey Arun , thanks all it takes was migration , its resolved now